# AngularJS and PubNub GCM Push Notifications

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I've been trying to implement push notifications using PubNub and their AngularJS SDK. However, I am receiving the message on my device but not a push notification through GCM.

I have the code below:

```
PubNub.ngPublish({
                            channel: channel,
                            message: {
                                "pn_gcm": {
                                    "data": {
                                        "summary": "Game update 49ers touchdown",
                                        "teams": ["49ers", "raiders"],
                                        "score": [7, 0],
                                        "lastplay": "5yd run up the middle"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

I get the message successfully with all the data but no Push notification when the app is in the background or closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Update:

I'm pasting this in the console:

```
{
"pn_gcm": {
        "data" : {
            "summary": "Game update 49ers touchdown",
            "teams" : ["49ers", "raiders"],
            "score" : [7, 0],
            "lastplay" : "5yd run up the middle"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the GCM API key is set correctly in the admin portal? (admin.pubnub.com)?

Comment: From pubnub.com/console, can you paste the JSON that is natively received from the subscriber?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. I'm pasting the message object in the console and the client is receiving it correctly. However, if I close the app I don't get a Push notification from GCM. (Please see my updated question)

Comment: The next thing I'd suggest is to publish data outside of PubNub natively via Google, and see if the app responds to it. But in the meantime, if you contact us at support@pubnub.com, we can help trace the message from our servers to Google to see where the disconnect may be.

Comment: Thanks, I've sent an e-mail :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207019/pubnub-push-notification-not-working-for-cross-platform-mobile-app see above link i have explain in that post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing push notifications has multiple parts. As it applies to pubnub:

1. registering your API key in the console and enabling push notifications. This enables you publish push notifications from the pubnub API
2. enable push notifications on the channels you intend to use for push  notifications. This step will register your device with the pubnub mobile-gateway for push and associate the device with the channels you are using for push.
3. Finally, you need to implement GCM in the app so that it knows what to do when it receives a push notification:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: **`This Answer is PubNub Approved!`**

Comment: see below link i have explain in detail there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207019/pubnub-push-notification-not-working-for-cross-platform-mobile-app